# Could not find builder-4.0.1.jar (com.android.tools.build:builder:4.0.1)

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-4.0

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ljky2.png)

I have a problem with building my project and I searched for 3 days straight and I tried everything but nothing worked. And right now I'm desperate.

Does anybody know how should I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

On **app\build.gradle** add this

```
implementation 'com.android.tools.build:builder:4.0.1'
```

and **sync**